# Convert scientific notation to decimal notation

Tags: java, numbers, scientific-notation

There is a similar question on SO which suggests using NumberFormat which is what I have done.

I am using the parse() method of NumberFormat.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

    DecToTime dtt = new DecToTime();
    dtt.decToTime("1.930000000000E+02");

}

public void decToTime(String angle) throws ParseException{

    DecimalFormat dform = new DecimalFormat();
    //ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(13);
    Number angleAsNumber = dform.parse(angle);

    System.out.println(angleAsNumber);
}
```

The result I get is

> 1.93

I didn't really expect this to work because 1.930000000000E+02 is a pretty unusual looking number, do I have to do some string parsing first to remove the zeros? Or is there a quick and elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use DecimalFormat with an expression in scientific notation, you need to specify a pattern.  Try something like

```
DecimalFormat dform = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
```

See the [javadocs for DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) -- there's a section marked "Scientific Notation".

Answer (score 3):

**Memorize the `String.format` syntax so you can convert your doubles and BigDecimals to strings of whatever precision without e notation:**

This java code:

```
double dennis = 0.00000008880000d;
System.out.println(dennis);
System.out.println(String.format("%.7f", dennis));
System.out.println(String.format("%.9f", new BigDecimal(dennis)));
System.out.println(String.format("%.19f", new BigDecimal(dennis)));
```

Prints:

```
8.88E-8
0.0000001
0.000000089
0.0000000888000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take your angle as a double, rather than a String, you could use [printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) magic.

`System.out.printf("%.2f", 1.930000000000E+02);`

displays the float to 2 decimal places. `193.00` .

If you instead used `"%.2e"` as the format specifier, you would get `"1.93e+02"`

(not sure exactly what output you want, but it might be helpful.)