# How can convert large Double no. in human readable formate

Tags: android, double

I want to print a double No. in TextView like this format 10699657.6, currently this is like 1.06996576E7 . please can any one help me?

Comment: This "1.06996576E7" is totally human readable :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat dform = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
```

Similar question found here:
[Convert scientific notation to decimal notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448573/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimal-notation)

Comment: @WasimAkram you still did not accept the answer. Click the CHECK MARK next to my answer and it will be green indicating that you accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class, which does exactly what you want.